# What is it about the Great Pyramid that makes it so amazing today?

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-construction

> 1. What is it **about the Great Pyramid** that makes it so amazing today?
>    [Source](https://10.%20What%20is%20it%20about%20the%20Great%20Pyramid%20that%20makes%20it%20so%20amazing%20today?)

2. What is it that makes **the Great Pyramid** so amazing today?

---

I'd like to know if sentences 1 and 2 are the same.
If they're not the same, I'd also like to know the difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are equivalent. You could also say, "What about the Great Pyramid makes it so amazing today?" or "What characteristic of the Great Pyramid makes it so amazing today?" or, more broadly, "Why is the Great Pyramid considered so amazing?" or "Why would one consider the Great Pyramid so amazing?".

Comment: They are very similar but 1 is specifically asking for reasons pertaining to the Pyramid (things about the pyramid, its qualities, its location, etc), while 2 is more general. If it was very popular because all the other tourist sites in Egypt were shut, then that would be a better answer for 2 than 1.